# Is there any predefined macro like _MSC_BUILD(supported from vs2008) in visual studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, predefined-macro

I hope for using any predefined macro like _MSC_BUILD (from vs2008) because I want to use revision number of compiler.

but i can't find that in vs2005.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The [predefined macros list for VS 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) shows `_MSC_VER` for getting the compiler versions.

Answer (score 0):

There were no (accessible) revision numbers in the days of VS2005, so sadly, no there isn't. See the following web site for a full list of available macros:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx